# If terms of an AP are primes.Find certain thing.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> if there are a finite  Arithmetic Progression  of k terms such that all the number are primes.find
>   common difference.

my attempt
 so a general term let it be $T_r$ where r is the position of the term should not be divisible by first term let it be $a_1$
mean t when divide by a should give  $T_r\mod a_1 ≡ x $ where x>0

what should i do next?

Note: The book from which i got this question gives a hint that answer is in form of k but the answer or how to do it is not given.So I am not sure that there is a define answer so that is why i am asking this.

Comment: There are multiple answers possible, depending on your value of $k$. You can get a restriction, but not a definite answer, as is implied in the question.

Comment: the answer will be in the terms of k but.

Comment: For $k = 2$, it's a long-standing conjecture that every even number works. For $k = 3$, the sequence $3, 5, 7$ has common difference $2$, the sequence $3, 7, 11$ has common difference $4$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule is that if you have a progression of $k$ terms, for primes less than $k$ either the difference is divisible by the prime or one of the numbers is divisible by the prime. For example, if $k=6$, either the difference is even, in which case all of the terms can be odd, or at least one term is even.  Again, either the difference is a multiple of $3$ or at least one term is a multiple of $3$ and the same for $5$.  As a result, the difference of terms must be a multiple of the product of all the primes less than $k$.  If $k$ is prime it must also include a factor $k$ unless the progression starts with $k$ like the examples $3,5,7$ or $5,11,17,23,29$.